# Seeking shapefiles for mapping innovation districts

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, district

The Brookings Institution has been promoting Innovation Districts as a useful geographical concept since 2014 (for example [here](https://www.brookings.edu/essay/rise-of-innovation-districts) and [here](https://www.brookings.edu/research/clusters-and-innovation-districts-lessons-from-the-united-states-experience)). I should think that mapping Innovation Districts precisely would be part of that research and indeed some maps are shown here and there. However, I have not been able to find a unified source of shapefiles for US Innovation Districts (even though the research has focused on the US). Maybe the sources vary city by city or maybe shapefiles are not systematically available even for the cities covered by the initial study. What are sources of shapefiles for all Innovation Districts or failing that sources for existing ones?

Comment: Just because it's a useful geographical concept and maybe used as a framework for administrative action doesn't mean there are official boundaries available. My guess is that you'll have to do your own research on the districts in the US and then create the boundaries yourself.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange is the place to ask.